# why does gnuplot label min/max values incorrectly?

Tags: gnuplot

I am creating a plot where I label the min and max values of a dual time series.

I do this by defining `min` and `max` functions, and plotting each series along with a label for the higher and lower value at each time point. The labels are offset up and down so there is not overlap with the lines.

[image: broken plot]

Note that the labels are always the value from the second column, regardless of whether the value in the first or second column is higher.

**The main problem seems to be that the min/max functions work as far as plotting points, but not for selecting labels.**

Why is this the case?

Here is my MWE:

```
set terminal pdfcairo size 3,2
set output 'output.pdf'

# min/max functions
min(x, y) = x > y ? y : x
max(x, y) = x > y ? x : y

set style data lines

# nice ranges
set xr [-1:5]
set yr [-1:3]

plot 'data.dat' u 0:1 title 'col 1', \
  '' u 0:2 title 'col 2', \
  '' u 0:(min($1,$2)) title 'min', \
  '' u 0:(max($1,$2)) title 'max', \
  '' u 0:(min($1,$2) - 0.2):(min($1,$2)) notitle with labels, \
  '' u 0:(max($1,$2) + 0.2):(max($1,$2)) notitle with labels
```

and data file:

```
1 2
2 0
1 2
1 0
0 1
```

Comment: I think you must explicitly use `sprintf` to format the label: `plot 'data.dat' u 0:(min($1,$2) - 0.2):(sprintf('%.0f', min($1,$2))) notitle with label`.

Comment: If you make your comment an answer I will accept it. That worked! I had suspected it had to do with string/numerical comparisons, and my experiments with casting to/from `int` did not work out.

Comment: I wasn't sure, but now I found also the link to an older, rejected bug report about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must explicitly use `sprintf` to format the label:

```
plot 'data.dat' u 0:(min($1,$2) - 0.2):(sprintf('%.0f', min($1,$2))) notitle with label
```

For some special cases the conversion to string is done automatically, but that is not guaranteed to work. You're safe only with `sprintf`. See also
https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1368/ for a longer discussion about this behaviour.